# How to close a mat-sidenav when a value(binding) changes?

Tags: angular

I've a mat-sidenav that shows a list of contacts.

- On mobile display, it comes over the view when clicking on a button.
- On a larger display, it gets displayed automatically and should not be closable.

The contact list is another component, so the the component basically looks like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container style="height: 100%">
  <mat-sidenav
    #sidenav
    role="directory"
    [mode]="mobileQuery.matches? 'over':'side'"
    [opened]="!mobileQuery.matches"
  >
    <app-contact-list
      [(selectedContact)]="selectedContact"
      [contacts]="contacts"
    >
    </app-contact-list
  ></mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="mainDiv">
      {{ selectedContact?.name }}
      <button *ngIf="mobileQuery.matches"
        mat-icon-button
        color="primary"
        (click)="sidenav.open()"
      >
        <mat-icon>list</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

while the typescript file is like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss'],
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  selectedContact: Contact;
  contacts: Observable<Contact[]>;
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  constructor(
    private chatService: ChatService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private media: MediaMatcher
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contacts = this.chatService.getContacts;
    this.contacts.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((v) => (this.selectedContact = v[0]));
    this.mobileQuery = this.media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addEventListener('change', this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mobileQuery.removeEventListener('change', this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
}
```

I need the sidenav to close once a contact is selected.

One issue is that the app-contact-list doesn't know that it's inside a sidenav that has to be closed.
The second issue is that the sidenav should only be closed when it's in "mobile" mode.

Is there a way to update the "opened" when the `selectedContact`change ?

Comment: Maybe through service ? Create a service that has a subject. Sidenav is subscribed, contact selected emits a value.

Comment: Angular material has a breakpoint observabele
https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview
Whic could help with the screen-size detection

Comment: @ОлегВойтинський The screen size detection is already working(but yes, I've fixed this). I could put a "setter" in the selectedContact, but I don't know how to close the sideNav from the typescript(and I was hopping there was a way to do this on the view)